# What loop/logic do I need to print out 5 separate lines of a single array element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, indexing

I am extremely new to coding and I am currently working on iterating over arrays. I am not sure why I am having trouble with this logic as I can already do a bunch of other stuff with arrays. I think I am forgetting some of the basics.

I am wanting to be able to print one of these array elements multiple times, either as a 'spam' e.g. printing out "Wave 1" 5 times in a row, or having a function that takes in a (num) and then spams it (num) times.

Here is the array:

> `const friendlyEmotes = ["Wave 1", "Wave 2", "Flirt 1", "Flirt 2", "Dance 1", "Dance 2", "High-five", "Laugh"]`

And this is my code:

```
const spamWave = function(num){
   for (let i = 0; i < num; i++){
   return friendlyEmotes[0];
   }
}
```

I realize I am not using 'i' in the return statement and therefore am not utilizing the loop, but that is where I am missing the logic or syntax in order to use 'i' to print out the element multiple times.

I tried indexOf with using [i] without success:

```
const spamWave = function(num){
   for (let i = 0; i < num; i++){
   return friendlyEmotes.indexOf(0)[i];
   }
}

// spamWave(5) returns 'undefined'
```

I hope I was able to make my question clear and concise.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you `return` in a loop, the function ends immediately at the `return` statement, so the loop stops. A function can't return more than one value. (And if you need more than one value from a function, you can return one array holding the values.)

Comment: Your response cleared up an error in my thinking. Thank you for bringing me this to my attention.

Answer (score 7):

You are returning the array element instead of logging it to the console. This should work for you: it's a function which takes an array, an index of the item in the array to log, and the number of times to log the element at the index:

```js
const friendlyEmotes = ["Wave 1", "Wave 2", "Flirt 1", "Flirt 2", "Dance 1", "Dance 2", "High-five", "Laugh"];

function logArrayElementAtIndex (arr, index, logCount) {
  for (let i = 0; i < logCount; i += 1) {
    console.log(arr[index]);
  }
}

logArrayElementAtIndex(friendlyEmotes, 0, 5);
```

Comment: I had forgotten that functions can take multiple arguments.

.. and you actually wrote the function. Thank you!